# Is changing connection string dynamically in web.config file using Entity Framework possible?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I want to change the connection string dynamically but I have no clue how to do that or either is it possible or not.

Comment: Connectionstring is nothing more than a string, if you know how to generate a string, you have half of this solved. Now pass the string to the connection-object whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to load the connection string from the web.config.  Implement a constructor on your DbContext that accepts a connection string, and you can supply whatever you want.

In EF Core it looks like this:

```
public class MyDatabase : DbContext
{
    readonly string connectionString;

    public MyDatabase(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

and in EF6 like this:

```
public class MyDatabase : DbContext
{
    public MyDatabase(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

Note that if you change the connection string dynamically, the DbContext will not be initialized multiple times.

Comment: thanks for revert. but the problem is i want to change connection string according to service selected by client. so connection always changed according to client

Comment: Ok, that should work.  Just use a different connection string for each client.  That’s a common pattern.